# if $Y$ and $Z$ be two closed subspace of banach space $X$ .Prove $p:X \mapsto Y$ is continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis

Here Y and Z are closed subspace of such that $Y\cap Z=\{0\}$and $X= Y+Z$ .I have to prove that $p:X \mapsto Y$ is continuous.where $p(y+z)=y $ $\forall y\in Y$ and$\forall z\in z$.                                                                                Obviously $p$ is well defined .To prove continuous, I  have to show for $||y|| \leq k||z+y||$  for some +ve real k.would you give me hints to prove it .

Comment: Hint: closed graph theorem.

Comment: @julien thanks to you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define $X=Y+Z=Y\times Z$. We have$$|z+y|=|z|+|y|$$ see the equivalent definition of the norm on $X$ at the wikipedia page.

Comment: i know the equivalent definition of norm.why this norm of  $X$ and norm of $Y+Z$ are equivalent.

Comment: You should try to prove this yourself. It is not that difficult.

Comment: ,thanks to you.

Comment: You are right ,it is not that difficult.

Comment: You are welcome.